# How do I check a username/password combination in OS X?

Tags: c++, c, macos, authentication

In windows I can call `LogonUserW` or on linux `pam_authenticate` to check whether a given username/password is correct. How do I do this on OS X (for c/c++)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://ditesh.gathani.org/blog/2011/06/pam-authentication-for-fun-and-profit/):

> PAM is a pluggable authentication and authorization library for *nix
>   based systems – think Linux, FreeBSD and even **Mac OS X** ....